# Makefile target: dollar sign dot o ( $.o %.h : %.idl )

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Since GNU make 3.82 one of Makefiles written by another person no longer works:

> ../../PPB_ROOT/ppb-team.mk:238: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.

line 238:

```bsh
$.o %.h : %.idl
    @echo Cleaning up previous output of idl...
    @-rm -f $@
    @echo Making $@...
    $(IDL_CMD)
    $(IDL_CXX_CMD)
    @ if [ "$(LOCAL_ORB)" != "OMNIORB" ]; then \
        $(OWN_MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) `basename '$*'`_skel.o; \
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) `basename '$*'`.a `basename '$*'`.o `basename '$*'`_skel.o; \
    else \
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) `basename '$*'`.a `basename '$*'`.o; \
    fi;
```

What '$.o' means? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a typeo, from the GNU make docs section 4.2:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

```
Because dollar signs are used to start make variable references, if you 
really want a dollar sign in a target or prerequisite you must write two
of them, ‘$$’
```

I would suspect it is supposed to be

```
%.o %.h : %.idl
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a [pattern rule that makes two targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) (see example 3). So, it should probably be:

```
%.o %.h : %.idl
```